# Xamarin - Unable to Deploy to Device

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run a Xamarin app on Android, that app was built in 2016 and I had to make a lot of changes and updates on the libraries to make it build, now it is building but when it tries to Deploy it on the device I am getting the following error

```
Target _LinkAssembliesShrink:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'InspectNTrack.SharedObjects.FPCOMM InspectNTrack.PortableLayer.UserModel::GetFPCOMM()' in assembly: 'PortableLayer.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve SQLite.CreateTableResult SQLite.SQLiteConnection::CreateTable(SQLite.CreateFlags)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x00013] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodReference reference) [0x0004a] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction instruction) [0x00040] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000c2] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x001b1] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x0001b] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue () [0x00047] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue () [0x0000a] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process () [0x00102] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000d] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000b] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000d] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x001dd] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask () [0x0001b] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1940,5): error XALNK7000:   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in <566aee05a7ab47e88eb61edcf5874648>:0 
Done building target "_LinkAssembliesShrink" in project "InspectNTrack.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "XXXX" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Any idea about what can be happening? I will really appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: `Failed to resolve SQLite.CreateTableResult SQLite.SQLiteConnection::CreateTable(SQLite.CreateFlags)` you haven't got the linking behaviour set to optimise references or something?

Comment: As a quick test, change your linker to Don't Link and see if it'll compile.